# Cypher matching with labels doesn't return any results on Neo4j 2.1.6

Tags: neo4j, cypher

ok i am really new in neo4j. However, this simple thing it doesn't work for some reason!!

This statement return 0 rows!

> Match (a:Movie) Return a limit 25

This statement return 0 rows!

> Match (a:Person) Return a limit 25

[image: image1]

However, if i do this line, i get results:

> Match (a) Return a limit 25

[image: image2]

I am using a fresh installed Neo4j 2.1.6 with a data set named "cineasts_12k_movies_50k_actors" taken from http://example-data.neo4j.org/files/cineasts_12k_movies_50k_actors.zip?_ga=1.201211559.867824426.1420106902 with allow_store_upgrade=true

So i am not sure if i am doing something wrong or there is a bug when i query using labels!

Comment: There is also a new dataset here: http://example-data.neo4j.org/files/cineasts_12k_movies_50k_actors_2.1.6.zip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By looking at the graph.db store files, it seems like this dataset is for a legacy version of Neo4j and does not use labels.

I have manually added the labels (Actor Label for actors, and Cineast labels for directors) and rezipped the db and you can download it from my dropbox.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/sxl0kxgw9t4iula/graph.db.zip?dl=0

I will pass this issue to Neo4j staff and we'll try to make a new release of the dataset.

In the meantime I can propose you to try Graphgen http://graphgen.neoxygen.io for generating a test graph and import it in your neo4j local instance.

Rik wrote a nice article about it here : http://blog.bruggen.com/2014/12/prototyping-graph-database.html

Also you can use the Movie Graph available in the start page of your neo4j instance browser.

Comment: This dataset is linked from Neo's page at http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-example-data/ and for use with a specific tutorial: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-graph/snapshot-site/reference/html/#tutorial. I don't think it's really intended for use outside of that. They should probably take that tutorial down entirely, it's too old.

Comment: Thanks your modification on the dataset worked. I've tried "Match (a:Cineast) Return a limit 25" http://i.imgur.com/TfjEXSv.jpg and tried "Match (a:Actor) Return a limit 25" http://i.imgur.com/kR0Uj7r.jpg